# XNA - Obtaining depth from the scene's render target?

Tags: xna, c#, rendertargets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Depth buffer and render target](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22318/depth-buffer-and-render-target)

I'm currently rendering my scene to a render target so it can be used for rendering methods such as post processing and order independent transparency.

```
rtScene = new RenderTarget2D(
            GraphicsDevice,
            GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
            false,
            SurfaceFormat.Rgba64,
            DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8,        // Requires a depth format for objects to be drawn correctly (e.g. wireframe model surrounding model)
            0,
            RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents
            );
```

I am required to use RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents so that the same render target can be rendered to multiple times, once for each of the draw methods below.

- DrawBackground
- DrawDeferred
- DrawForward
- DrawTransparent

The problem is that DrawTransparent requires a copy of the scene's depth as a texture.

Is there any way to obtain this from the scene render target above (rtScene)?

I can't have more than one render target with RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents as this causes problems on hardware such as the XBOX 360, so rendering the depth to a separate render target at the same time as I render the scene isn't possible as far as I can tell.

Would I be able to get around this problem by "Ping-Ponging" two render targets (using the more compatible RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents) and using the result for the depth texture?

Comment: Not possible with 1 render target I am afraid. See @Jonathan Dickinson's answer to a similar question for workarounds. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23854/8119

Comment: _Not possible with 1 render target I am afraid._  It would seem that my "Ping-Ponging" idea is probably the best way forward.  Thank you.